# "open files" ulimit: controlling via limits.conf

Tags: linux, redhat, ulimit

I'm banging my head on this, and I can't understand why it's not working.  I'm hoping that someone can shed light on this, or failing that, give me some suggestions for avenues of investigation.

I've got a Red Hat 7.3 system (don't ask) where it's desirable to increase the open files limit for the `wls81` user.  I thought that I was just not able to control it, but it increasingly looks as if I've only got the problem with the user I need to change.  I've added the following lines to `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
wls81       soft    nofile      10100
wls81       hard    nofile      10240
madhatta    soft    nofile      10100
madhatta    hard    nofile      10240
```

`pam_limits.so` is being properly invoked, as far as I can tell:

```
[madhatta@server madhatta]$ sudo grep limits /etc/pam.d/*
/etc/pam.d/login:session    required     /lib/security/pam_limits.so
/etc/pam.d/sshd:session    required     /lib/security/pam_limits.so
/etc/pam.d/su:session    required     /lib/security/pam_limits.so
/etc/pam.d/system-auth:session     required      /lib/security/pam_limits.so
```

When I ssh in as myself, I get the new soft limit, and can increase up to the hard limit:

```
desktop> ssh server
Last login: Thu May 10 13:20:13 2012 from a.b.c.d
[madhatta@server madhatta]$ ulimit -n 
10100
[madhatta@server madhatta]$ ulimit -n 10200
[madhatta@server madhatta]$ ulimit -n 
10200
[madhatta@server madhatta]$ ulimit -n 10300
bash: ulimit: cannot modify open files limit: Operation not permitted
```

but when I ssh in as the `wls81` user, I can't:

```
desktop> ssh wls81@server
Last login: Wed May  9 22:29:33 2012 from a.b.c.d
[wls81@server wls81]$ ulimit -n
1024
[wls81@server wls81]$ ulimit -n 10000
bash: ulimit: cannot modify open files limit: Operation not permitted
```

The same happens when I `su -` to each user.  I honestly can't see why this user's not able to have its `ulimit`s reset.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the mystery is solved.  I found that when I did `su - wls81` I got the 1024 limit, but when I just did `su wls81` I got the new, higher limit.  It turns out that wls81's `.bash_profile` invoked another script, which in turn invoked an environment-setting script from a completely different user on the system, which did a `ulimit -n 1024`.

When I removed that line, wls81 now gets the new limit.

Comment: The great thing is you debug yurself. +1 for that.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, like you faced. Can we do a chat discussion for that. Please.

Comment: jhamb, I'm happy to try to help but am working onsite the next couple of days so can't do a chat until next week.  Feel free to email me, though; my personal website is listed in my profile, and my work-related email address is on there.

Comment: ohk. I will mail that to you. Can I tell the problem here.Please

Comment: When I run command `ulimit -n` it gives `12000`
when I run `rsh localhost ulimit -n` , it gives `12000`
Now, the actual problem is here, we build a modified-rsh, that have some extra features.
When I use, `modified-rsh localhost ulimit -n` , it shows `1024`
WHY ???

Comment: It's a free world, I can't stop you - but generally comments with new problems in are frowned on, on SF.  I think you would do better to open a new question, describing your problem in detail, and including a link to this question to say you've read it and it hasn't helped; that way lots of SF users may be able to join in and help you.  It's what we like to do!

Comment: ohk, I put the question as new question, I also show some hint of my question in above comment. One thing you seem like a philosopher that's interesting.

Comment: Most sysadmins are at least partly philosophers!

Comment: Question's link is http://serverfault.com/questions/487426/why-ulimit-shows-diffrerent-outputs

I am waiting for your reply on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might also need to check and probably set max filedescriptors for open files in kernel:

```
sudo systcl fs.file-max
```

and edit /etc/sysctl.conf to make changes permanent.

Comment: Nope, that limit's currently much higher (314570).  And if you read my question, you'll see that I have successfully changed the ulimit for another user on that system; so whatever's stopping me, it's not system-wide.  Good guess, though!