# "Open files" ulimit applied only when using 'su - userX' but not when I SSH into server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ulimit

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. My problem is that the ulimit values described in `limits.conf` are not being applied when I SSH into my server using a non root account. Either that or they are being applied and overridden.

I've added the appropriate values in `/etc/security/limits.conf`

```
* soft nofile 64000
* hard nofile 64000
```

I don't want it to apply to the root, so this is fine. I've also added `session required pam_limits.so` to the files in `/etc/pam.d`. Added to

```
/etc/pam.d/login
/etc/pam.d/common-session
/etc/pam.d/sshd
/etc/pam.d/su
```

And I've rebooted my server a couple of times. However the file open limit always shows as 1024 for soft and 4096 for hard. My `.bashrc` and `.profile` for the user in question files do not seem to contain anything that would change this value.

If I login as root and run the command via su, then I get the expected ulimit.

```
su nodeserver
ulimit -n
#result is 64000
```

But the when I SSH as nodeserver I get a value of 4096.

1. Are there any other places I should look at where this value might be set?
2. Can I look at a list of startup scripts / commands that ran when the nodeserver user logged in?

It's pretty much what's going on here except there doesn't seem to be anything in my startup scripts - ["open files" ulimit: controlling via limits.conf](https://serverfault.com/questions/387884/open-files-ulimit-controlling-via-limits-conf)

Comment: i did the exact same thing and this caused me unable to ssh anymore, what do I do? Can you help http://serverfault.com/questions/792505/unable-to-access-ubuntu-ec2-ssh-connection-to-server-ip-closed