# Unable to access Ubuntu EC2 ssh, Connection to Server-IP Closed

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, ulimit, sysctl

My server was having error due to high traffic and it showed this message often when I access the website

```
Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open '/home/ubuntu/chat2/public/style.css'
    at Error (native)
```

To fix this, I googled and tried to increase the Ulimit in Ubuntu.

Recently I changed the following files

```
sysctl.conf
```

as I followed this tutorial http://ithubinfo.blogspot.in/2013/07/how-to-increase-ulimit-open-file-and.html

and also changed

```
/etc/security/limits.conf
```

After I did that, I logged out of my ssh and then tried logging in and since then I am unable to get in.

It logs in and then tell me that Connection to (server ip) closed.

See [image]

How can I get access to my terminal back and/or restore my `limits.conf` and `sysctl.conf` ?

UPDATE:

i tried accessing it via FTP File zilla and it gives error "Unexpected end of file SFTP".
[image]

How do I edit those files again without terminal access?

Comment: There is something in your server that initially has too many open files. It might be compromised, or there might be misconfigured software. You should have fixed the root cause, not alleviate symptoms..

Comment: what do the server logs say?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen How can i get access to ssh and sftp back?

Comment: @Jakuje I can't access my EC2 server ubunut, as  I can't get into via SSH or via SFTP. How can I get to see the logs?  Is there any way to see the logs from AWS online console?

Comment: Stop (NOT terminate) the instance and start another one with a officially provided AMI from Ubuntu or so. Attach the EBS volume which is the root volume from your currently running instance to the new instance and mount it. Now you can access all files and modify them. Afterwards you can reattach the EBS volume back and start your instance again.